# Why foldr is not lazy for tuples in haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold

It's ok to write something like that:

```
head $ foldr (:) [] [1..]
-- 1
```

But when I try to deal with tuples it goes to infinity loop:

```
head . fst $ foldr (\ x (ls, _) -> (x : ls, 0)) ([], 0) [1..]
```

The reason I need this is because I want to pass count of produced elements in inner function. Like that:

```
foldr go ([], 0) [1..]
go num (ls, cnt) = -- use cnt to get l and produce new pair (l : ls, cnt + 1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pattern matches are by default strict.  That is,

```
(\(x,y) -> (1:x,y)) _|_ = _|_
```

You can use a lazy pattern match using the `~` pattern, though:

```
(\ ~(x,y) -> (1:x,y)) _|_ = (1:_|_, _|_)
```